# What feats can an animal companion take?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, animal-companions

The [druid](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/druid.htm)'s [animal companion](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/druid.htm#animalCompanion) says, "An animal companion gains additional... feats for bonus HD as normal for advancing a monster’s Hit Dice."

Can an animal companion take feats from any category and source?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can take any feat that the animal companion qualifies for.**

No, really, you can. A list, suggestions, and etc. could be very long. [Mooncrow's Handle Animal Guide](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=1300.0) is a good handbook to give a good read to help you in deciding. Not only does it cover feats, but it also covers skills, equipment, templates, and so on.